# Efficient Encoding Schemes

Tags: encoding, hardware

I want to choose a encoding scheme for data storage. I have very low available memory. which coding should be best to optimally utilize available space. 
ANSI, UTF or any other..

Data is the Capital Alphabetics

Comment: Well, **what will be stored?**

Comment: Alphabetic chracters A-Z

Comment: Have you considered using a 5bit character set, if you only want the capital letters from the English alphabet?

Comment: @RowlandShaw No I donot use 5bit character. Kindly explain it for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the frequency distribution of letters, [Huffman Coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) is a good balance between complexity, speed and efficiency.

If you don't know the distribution of letters or they are random, just store them 5 bits at a time. For example, consider the string "ABCDE". The letter numbers are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. Converted to binary, this is:

```
00000 00001 00010 00011 00100
```

Now you just group every 8 bits into bytes:

```
00000000 01000100 00110010 0xxxxxxx
```

You need to store the length too, so that you know that there is no useful data in the last byte's 7 bits.

If code space is of no concern and you just want to pack the strings as well as you can, you could use Huffman coding or Arithmetic coding even with a uniform frequency distribution to pack each character into log2(26) bits on average, which is slightly less than 5 (namely, 4.7 bits).